# Swift: animating uilayoutconstraints and changing alpha causes crash

Tags: swift, animation, nslayoutconstraint

Why is this code causing a SIGABT error?

```
@IBAction func showDial(_ sender: Any) {

        var dialBottom:CGFloat = lcDialBottom!.constant

        if dialBottom == -600 {
            //move up
            dialBottom = -400
        } else {
            //move down
            dialBottom = -600
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
            animations: {
                self.lcDialBottom.constant = dialBottom
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
                self.btnShowDial.alpha = 0.0
       })
    }
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSLayoutConstraint setAlpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002ff8d70'
```

I understand what the error is saying, NSLayoutConstraint does not have a setAlpha method, but I'm not calling it on a NSLC, I'm calling set alpha on a UIButton, which does have a setAlpha.

Here's my properties:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnShowDial: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lcDialBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Comment: Maybe you connected btnShowDial with layout constraint? Check it in storyboard.

Comment: You are correct. Make it an answer and I'll give you the bump! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check connection of btnShowDial in storyboard. Maybe you connected this IBOutlet with layout constraint.